# Get Jira tickets using Jira API and C#

Tags: c#, api, rest, integration, jira

```
public ActionResult getJiraTickets(string username, string password, string jiraUrl)
{   
   string queryString = jiraUrl + "/rest/api/2/search";

   var client = new HttpClient { BaseAddress = new Uri(queryString) };

   var credentials = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(username + ":" + password);

   client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Basic", Convert.ToBase64String(credentials));

   client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));

   HttpResponseMessage response = client.GetAsync(queryString).Result;

   if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
   {
      // use response      
   }
}
```

I get StatusCode: 401, ReasonPhrase: 'Unauthorized' in the response.

The queryString is correct because if I hit that URI using the browser I get a JSON response back.

Username and password are correct as well.

What am I doing wrong in the code?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I apologise for not posting this as a comment, I don't have enough rep yet to post a comment.

I know you say your username and password are correct but I would double check them because I have taken your code and run it with my login details and Jira Url and it worked as expected.

Comment: I don't know what to say. I keep checking the credentials and they are correct